# System property is always null in maven project

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

My utility class

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
        ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        String profile = System.getProperty("env");
        //InputStream in = loader.getResourceAsStream(fileName + ".properties");
        InputStream in = loader.getResourceAsStream(fileName + "_" + profile + ".properties");
```

always return null.

I did add properties-maven-plugin in pom

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>set-system-properties</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <properties>
                            <property>
                                <name>env</name>
                                <value>prod</value>
                            </property>
                        </properties>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

but still no luck in getting the property value in util class.

Comment: `String env = System.getProperty("env");`: where is that code and when does it run?

Comment: Which Maven goal do you run?

Comment: @MoritzPetersen yes. no luck with that

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand the documentation of the `set-system-properties` goal, it sets environment variables on the current machine. Depending on how it does that, those environment variables can be defined for the duration of the build only, the current user only or, if you have admin rights also for the current machine.

In any case, it will only set the variable on the machine where the project was built on.

If I understand your issue correctly, you want to store whether the build was a `release` (production) or a `debug` build?

In that case, you can use the `maven-assembly-plugin` and define a manifest value. This manifest value will be written to the jar's manifest which you can read at runtime, e. g. using the JCabi Manifest library.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
<systemProperties>
    <systemProperty>
        <name>env</name>
        <value>prod</value>
    </systemProperty>
</systemProperties>
```

Answer (score 0):

As a sidenote - If you are using surefire for running this when you see the error you should probably be using its built in system property functionality:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <systemPropertyVariables>
            <env>prod</env>
        </systemPropertyVariables>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```